# Custom user events using micrometer

Tags: spring-boot, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I’m new to micrometer. I want to record  events such as user registrations, user logins etc. Can I do this with micrometer and Spring Boot and show the data in Prometheus/Grafana?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. However you would be recording the events in aggregate. For example you might have a `counter` for logins. Over time you would be able to see how many logins had occurred and at what rate.

You wouldn't be tracking how many times user1234 had logged in. (You could force it to do that, but it isn't a good fit for that use case)

Comment: Great thanks, global numbers of logins is fine. I’ll try to find some examples but this means I can track all stats (operational and functional) for my micro services in one place.